# How do I select the first row in a UIPickerView on first load?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uipickerview

The way I have my picker view setup is to change a text field when I select one of the options.

```
    [dataArray addObject:@"1"];
    [dataArray addObject:@"2"];
    [dataArray addObject:@"3"];
```

When I tried to select the first option on the first load it wont change text field. However I can select the first option in the UIPickerView if I scroll up a little and then let it drop down on first option or scroll to option 2 then scroll back up to option 1. Is there a way to detect touch on first option and let it select it and change to that option? If so, what is the best course of action to doing this.

Comment: If all you want to do is initialize the text field to the first option, why do you need to have it done through the picker view?  Why not just directly set the text field to [dataArray objectAtIndex:0]?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand correctly, you are using the delegate to be notified of changes to selection in the picker view and set your text field accordingly? If so, you can call `[self pickerView:self.pickerView didSelectRow:0 inComponent:0]` after the picker view has been loaded, so that the first element appears in the text field.

Comment: Thats a decent solution, but is there a way where it wont populate the text field first,only if its clicked on?

Comment: If the picker view does not detect a tap as selection, it would be difficult and error prone detecting the tap. You could set up a tap gesture recognizer, but then there is a large margin for error. I suggest you stay with this compromise.

Comment: Rather than calling the delegate method, you really should use selectRow:inComponent:animated:.

Comment: Calling selectRow programmatically will not trigger the delegate method.

Comment: @LeoNatan, you saved my life. Thank you.